# Equivalents forms of $\diamondsuit$

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I'm trying to see that assuming $\diamondsuit$ the following holds:

1. Exists $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ such that $A_\alpha\subset\alpha\times\alpha$ and for every $A\subset \omega_1\times\omega_1$ the set $\{\alpha\in\omega_1: \alpha\times\alpha\cap A=A_\alpha\}$ is stationary.
2. Exists $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ such that $f_\alpha:\alpha\rightarrow \alpha$ and for every $f:\omega_1\rightarrow\omega_1$ the set $\{\alpha\in\omega_1: f\upharpoonright \alpha=f_\alpha\}$ is stationary.

Is anybody willing to give me a proof of this two facts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the assumption $\diamondsuit$?

Comment: @coffeemath See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For the first one let $h:\omega_1\times\omega_1\to\omega_1$ be a bijection. Let $C=\{\alpha\in\omega_1:h[\alpha\times\alpha]=\alpha\}$, and show that $C$ is a club set in $\omega_1$. Then consider the sets $h^{-1}[A_\alpha]$ for $\alpha\in C$.

For the second, let $h$ and $C$ be as above. For $\alpha\in C$ let

$$f_\alpha=\begin{cases}
\{\langle\xi,\eta\rangle\in\omega_1\times\omega_1:h(\langle\xi,\eta\rangle)\in A_\alpha\},&\text{if this is a function}\\
\varnothing,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and for $\alpha\in\omega_1\setminus C$ let $f_\alpha=\varnothing$.